# Блокировка прокрутки по умолчанию

Tags: android

Нужно заблокировать `ScrollView` от ручной прокрутки. При этом должны работать методы `scrollTo` и `scrollBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте свой кастомный скроллвью, наследуя его от `ScrollView` и переопределяя нужные методы как угодно.